# Module Import Problem for TesseractOCRiOS Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tesseract

I am willing to use Tesseract-OCR-iOS framework in my app. I am using Xcode 14.2 and I had several problems implementing it.

First, I started with installing the framework given in the github page above using Carthage. In the terminal I got the following line: [which is about the architecture it will build on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLYFK.png). I am working with a MacBook Pro with Apple M2 Pro chip on it. As it states, I tried to re-install the package with "carthage update --use-xcframeworks" and here is the output in the terminal: [which there is no error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IleiC.jpg).

Then, when I tried to import the framework, build failed and I get the following error: [which says "No such module 'TesseractOCR'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQzBX.png).

Afterwards, in the project navigator, in project Targets section, Build Phases tab, I manually added the TesseractOCR.framework file as follows: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2PUx.png). (I chose the file under the Carthage/Build/Static/iOS file which I am not sure if it is the correct one.) After that, in the project navigator pane 'Products' and 'Frameworks' file groups appeared and when I type "Import TesseractOCR" in the main view controller it appeared as suggestion and I assume that it can link with the framework now. However, build still fails with following error message:
"In /Users/.../Desktop/TessaractDemo1/Carthage/Build/iOS/Static/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR(TesseractOCR_vers.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/.../Desktop/TessaractDemo1/Carthage/Build/iOS/Static/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR' for architecture arm64."

Then again, in the Targets sectipn, Build Settings tab, I manually added 'arm64' in Excluded Architectures [as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc87M.png). I also added the tessdata folder to the target for English, downloaded from here https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/bf82613055ebc6e63d9e3b438a5c234bfd638c93. Then, build succeeds but when I try to instantiate a Tesseract object, build fails and I get the following error:

[Undefined symbol error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNahK.png). Then, I look General tab in Targets and noticed that under the Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content TesseractOCR.framework set to 'Do Not Embed'. I set it to 'Embed & Sign'. But this does not change anything.

So, I thought that maybe I should use Pod instead of Carthage for installation as it is given in wiki of the github page. But I got similar errors mentioned above. I could not figure out if there is anything I can do to use this framework, or maybe it is not compatible with the chip that I use. There are several topics for problems using Tesseract framework for iOS but I could not find problem similar to mine.

Thanks for your help.